# How to make a correct unit test for this controller with Jest

Tags: typescript, express, jestjs, typeorm, ts-jest

Well, I'm trying to understand how I could unit test my Controller on my express app, but I haven't found out how to do so... These are my code files for now:

```js
// CreateUserController.ts
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { CreateUserService } from "../services/CreateUserService";

class CreateUserController {
    async handle(request: Request, response: Response) {
        try {
            const { name, email, admin, password } = request.body;

            const createUserService = new CreateUserService();

            const user = await createUserService.execute({ name, email, admin, password });
            
            // if(user instanceof Error) {
            //     return response.send({ error: user.message });
            // }

            return response.send(user);
        } catch (error) {
            return response.send({ error });
        }
    }
}

export { CreateUserController };
```

```js
// CreateUserService.ts
import { getCustomRepository } from "typeorm";
import { UsersRepositories } from "../repositories/UsersRepositories";
import { hash } from "bcryptjs";

interface IUserRequest {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    admin?: boolean;
    password: string;
}

class CreateUserService {
    async execute({ name, email, admin = false, password }: IUserRequest) {
            const usersRepository = getCustomRepository(UsersRepositories);

            if(!email) {
                throw new Error('Incorrect e-mail.');
            }

            const userAlreadyExists = await usersRepository.findOne({ email });

            if(userAlreadyExists) {
                throw new Error('User already exists.');
            }

            const passwordHash = await hash(password, 8);

            const user = usersRepository.create({ name, email, admin, password: passwordHash });

            const savedUser = await usersRepository.save(user);

            return savedUser;
    }
}

export { CreateUserService };
```

```js
// Users.ts
import { Entity, PrimaryColumn, Column, CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn } from "typeorm";
import { Exclude } from "class-transformer";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";

@Entity("users")
class User {

    @PrimaryColumn()
    readonly id: string;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column()
    email: string;

    @Column()
    admin: boolean;

    @Exclude()
    @Column()
    password: string;

    @CreateDateColumn()
    created_at: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updated_at: Date;

    constructor() {
        if (!this.id) {
            this.id = uuid();
        }
    }
}

export default User;
```

```js
// UsersRepositories.ts
import { EntityRepository, Repository } from "typeorm";
import User from "../entities/User";

@EntityRepository(User)
class UsersRepositories extends Repository<User> {}

export { UsersRepositories };
```

and what I want to test is the CreateUserController, but I think it is written in a way I can't test, or can I?
For now, I have something like this:

```js
// CreateUserController.unit.test.ts
import { CreateUserController } from "./CreateUserController";
import { getCustomRepository } from "typeorm";
import { UsersRepositories } from "../repositories/UsersRepositories";
import { hash } from "bcryptjs";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";


describe('testando', () => {
    it('primeiro it', async () => {
        const userId = uuid();
        const userData = {
            name: 'Fulano',
            email: 'email@d.com',
            password: '123456',
            admin: true
        };
        const returnUserData = {
            id: userId,
            name: 'Fulano',
            email: 'email@d.com',
            password: await hash('123456', 8),
            admin: true,
            created_at: new Date(),
            updated_at: new Date()
        };

        jest.spyOn(getCustomRepository(UsersRepositories), 'save').mockImplementation(async () => returnUserData);

        const user = await CreateUserController.handle(userData);
    });
});
```

Yeah, I know there are errors and it won't run, but that's all I got so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit test for the controller means another controller's dependencies work well. In your case, the controller only has one dependence - `CreateUserService`.

To test the controller, you can imagine that the service returns a user or throw an unexpected exception. And you expect that `.send` function will be called with the correct parameter.

There are too many things that need to explain(I think so), you can try to investigate by yourself.

```
// CreateUserController.test.ts
import { mocked } from "ts-jest/utils";
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { CreateUserController } from "./CreateUserController"
import { CreateUserService } from "./CreateUserService";

jest.mock('./CreateUserService'); // mock CreateUserService constructor

describe('CreateUserController', () => {
  const name = 'name';
  const email = 'email';
  const admin = true;
  const password = 'password';

  let controller: CreateUserController;
  let service: jest.Mocked<CreateUserService>;

  let request: Request;
  let response: Response;

  beforeEach(() => {
    request = {
      body: { name, email, admin, password },
    } as Request;
    response = {
      send: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    } as any;

    service = {
      execute: jest.fn(),
    }; // an instance of the service
    mocked(CreateUserService).mockImplementation(() => {
      return service;
    }); // mock the service constructor to return our mocked instance

    controller = new CreateUserController();
  });

  it('should response with user object when service returns the user', async () => {
    const user: any = 'user mocked';
    service.execute.mockResolvedValue(user);

    await controller.handle(request, response);

    expect(response.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith(user);
    expect(service.execute).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith({ name, email, admin, password });
  });

  it('should response with status 500 and error object when service throws a error', async () => {
    const error = new Error('Timed out!');
    service.execute.mockRejectedValue(error);

    await controller.handle(request, response);

    expect(response.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(500);
    expect(response.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ error });
    expect(service.execute).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith({ name, email, admin, password });
  });
});
```

It will fail in the second case because I expect that the controller has to respond with status 500, to make it pass, let update your controller:

```
...
    } catch (error) {
      return response.status(500).send({ error });
    }
...
```

Comment: Ok, that works, but I can't understand it completely. I'm just gonna use this file to study more about unit tests, thanks. Just one last thing: For making all unit tests in my project, should I write test files for CreateUserService.ts and UsersRepositories.ts, or just for the controllers?

Comment: @JoãoCasarin Testing for repositories are redundant (I think so), let's make unit test for services also because they include so much logic.

Comment: hmm, ok, would you mind to give me a direction for services testing?

Comment: @JoãoCasarin Mock `getCustomRepository` and test.

Comment: Hey @hoangdv I tried to follow your advice, and got 'something', but i still get errors... could you please take a look on my another post? This is it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69167760/properly-testing-typeorm-service